# AWS S3 SVG File is read as binary/octet-stream

Tags: amazon-web-services, svg, amazon-s3, amazon-waf

I have an icon assets located on s3, and have a page in angular that looks like this

```
<img alt="Some Logo" src="assets/icons/logo.svg" width="200">
```

It used to always work properly.

But recently after I apply AWS WAF for network restriction. It works for 1 day and then it never work again (never show the image anymore).

If I take a look at the developer tools, it showed up as binary/octet-stream
[image]

Instead of svg (this is back when I did not apply AWS WAF)

[image]

Any advice on how to fix this? I'm pretty sure it works even with AWS WAF at least for a day, unless there's some caching issue happening that I did not know of.

Answer (score 1):

On old versions of python, the python library mimetypes didnt have a definition for svg file types.

See this issue: https://bugs.python.org/issue19377

I added `'.svg' : 'image/svg+xml',` into the `types_map` in `mimetypes.py` and then the aws cli got the correct type for SVGs.